# session invalidate and creating a new session

Tags: jakarta-ee, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, mxunit

I'm using ColdFusion 10 and J2EE session variables. To log a user out ([end a session](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html)) I'm using `getPageContext().getSession().invalidate()` this works fine until I run my MXUnit tests and one of them tests the logout process. The session is invalidated and subsequent tests fail because there is not an active session. Is there a way to create a new session without reloading the page?

Comment: Have you trued using `sessionInvalidate()`? It is new to ColdFusion 10

Comment: @ScottStroz `sessionInvalidate()` doesn't invalidate J2EE session variables.

Comment: There is a note on the page that you referenced - _You cannot destroy the session and create a session on the same request, as creating a new session involves sending session cookies back._

Comment: @Miguel-F thanks, reading is hard. i'll update the test suite to run these last which should fix the issue.

Comment: @MattBusche - sometimes you just need another set of eyes. Happens to me quite a bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For better visibility from the comments*

I don't think you can create a new session without sending/receiving data from the client. There is a note on the [page that you referenced](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html) (at the bottom):

> You cannot destroy the session and create a session on the same request, as creating a new session involves sending session cookies back.